# Find relationship between A and B

Tags: inequality

$x^2>y^2$ and $x> -|y|$. Compare quantity A with quantity B (i.e. Determine whether $A>B$, or $A<B$, or $A=B$, or Cannot determine from the given information)

Quantity A: $x$

Quantity B: $y$

What I did to solve the problem is inputting values as follows-

x= 2, y= 1 --> True (satisfy both equations)

x= 2, y= -1 --> True

x= -2, y= 1 --> False

x= -2, y= -1 --> False

So, either way A>B. However, If I want to solve it without inputting values, how can I approach?

Answer (score 1):

If $x^2>y^2$ then $|x|>|y|$ (magnitude of $x$ > magnitude of $y$). So on the number line if we take $x$ and $-x$ then y would definitely lie between $x$ and $-x$. if we plot $y$ and $-y$ ,then these two would also lie between $x$ and $-x$. Now it is given that $x>-|y|$.

If $x>-|y|$ i.e. if we have negative value of i.e. sign of $y$ is -ive then $-|y|=y$ but if we have positive value of $y$ then $-|y|=-y$, that's how in both the cases we get $-|y|$ on negative part of number line. Now if we see that $x>-|y|$ , and we have that $y$ lies between $x$ and $-x$ then definitely $x>y$

Answer (score 1):

Think about the cases of the sign of $x$.  If $x \lt 0$ you should be able to show that one of your conditions is violated. Now show $x \gt y$